# Angular Material: multiple mat-menus - how to override their widths when each of them has to be different?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a situation where multiple mat-menus should be openable, the problem is that they can't have the same width.

[image]

So there are four mat-menus, one should be narrow, the other wide.. and I was able to change the widt only using `::ng-deep` but it affects all of them.

I was searching for a different solution and found something like this:

1. add class to mat-menu element:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="mat-menu-main" xPosition="before">
```

2. try to do something like this in its css:

```
.mat-menu-panel.mat-menu-main {
  width: 20rem;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
```

Every other solution that I found is with `::ng-deep` which I can't use..
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a class and then controlling the width using the class will work (it is the method I use).

The class must be defined in your global style sheet, not at the component level.

Comment: You are right, it can be done from the global level. But I wonder if it can be done from the component level.

Comment: it can but you need to set `viewEncapsulation` to `none` for the component - this has potential side effects - https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation